# How to install wxwidgets on Eclipse Mars.2 Mac?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, wxwidgets

I want to start doing some c++ but need it to be cross platform. I have found wxWidgets as a GUI solution and will use some of their SQL solutions for my program.

I tried searching the internet for how to install wxwidgets on Eclipse Mac but no luck. Haven't found anything that I can wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets is a C++ cross-platform and cross-compiler solution. It means that you don't need to install it. You can just compile it and use it to develop a software.

In order to compile this library, you should have a C/C++ compiler (clang or gcc on OSX/Mac) and their toolchain. Also if you plan to develop for OSX, you shuold have an OSX/Cocoa SDK installed (it is installed automatically with Xcode, have no idea about Eclipse).

In order to do so, you should:

1. Install C/C++ compiler (either with Xcode or Eclipse or any other IDE you have available).
2. Download latest wxWidgets release and unpack to you home diectory.
3. Open up a Terminal and issue following commands:

   a. cd ~/wxWidgets

   b. mkdir buildMac

   c. cd buildMac

   d. ../configure --enable-debug --with-cocoa --with-mac-osx-version-min=10.7 && make

   e. ./wx-config --cxxflags

   f. ./wx-config --libs
4. Open up Eclipse and start a new C++ project. If you are on OSX you may choose C++ bundle application.
5. Open the project properties and copy the results of the commands 3e and 3f to the project properties where appropriate. Consult with Eclipse manual/ML/forum to understand where to put that info.
6. Copy the file ~/wxWidgets/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp to you project directory and add this file to you project. Compile and run the project.

If you get stuck with any of the above instructions or get an error during compilation of either library or your project - don't hesitate to ask either here or open another thread.

Also, you can register on the wxWidgets forum at forums.wxWidets.org and subscribe to the wx-users ML.

Good luck.